# Filter on custom column in Fiori

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have custom column placed in smart table. It should have sort and filter option on column but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```html
<smartTable:smartTable entityset="foo">
 <ui:Table>
  <ui:columns>
   <ui:Column>
    <ui:CustomData>
     <core:CustomData key="p13Data" value='\{"columnKey": "key", "columnIndex":"0", "leadingProperty":"key", "isCurrency":"true", "sortProperty":"key", "filterProperty":"key" }'/>
    </ui:CustomData>
    <Text text="Column name"/>
    <ui:template>
     <HBox>
      <Text renderWhitespace="true" text="{key} "/>
      <core:Icon src="sap-icon://warning" visible={= ${key} === 'XX' ? true : false }> </core:Icon>
     </HBox>
    </ui:template>
   </ui:Column>
  </ui:columns>
 </ui:Table>
</smartTable:smartTable>
```

Comment: If it's a custom column I think you have to add it to the filter object in event handler `beforeRebindTable`. You can add additional filters and sorters there.